# pyspark and reduceByKey: how to make a simple sum

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying some code in Spark (pyspark) for an assignment.  First time I use this environment, so for sure I miss something…

I have a simple dataset called c_views.

If I run 
`c_views.collect()`

I get
`[…]
 (u'ABC', 100),
 (u'DEF', 200),
 (u'XXX', 50),
 (u'XXX', 70)]
[…]`

What I need to achieve is the **sum across all words**. So my guess is that I should get something like:

`(u'ABC', 100),
 (u'DEF', 200),
 (u'XXX', 120)`

So what I am trying to do is (following the hints in the assignment):

first I define the function `sum_views(a,b)` for the input dataset,
and then run a reduceByKey i.e.

`c_views.reduceByKey(sum_views).collect()`

However I do not understand what exactly I have to code in the function. I am trying many things but I always get an error. Does the workflow make sense? Other simple ways to achieve the result?

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a hint - this is a low quality question. Please read [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and try to make some efforts before posting. If you checked  [basic Spark examples](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) or [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey) you would find the answer without any effort.

Answer (score 2):

> Other simple ways to achieve the result?

```
from operator import add 

c_views.reduceByKey(add)
```

or if you prefer lambda expressions:

```
c_views.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

> I do not understand what exactly I have to code in the function

It has to be a function which takes two values of the same types as the values in your RDD and returns a value of the same type as inputs. It also has to be [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) which means that the final result cannot depend how do you arrange parentheses.